# Почему не работает "карусель" на андроиде

Tags: карусель, слайдер, android

Взял библиотеку [отсюда](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3289)

Самый простой вариант с установками по умолчанию.
Компиляция проходит без ошибок. Приложение открывается на устройстве и показывает пустое поле вместо карусели. Остальные элементы отображаются и функционируют нормально.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

--------------------класс ---------------------------

```
package com.google.v1; // <-- это неправда, как вы понимаете

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView;
import com.synnapps.carouselview.ImageListener;

public class CarouselViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CarouselView carouselView;

int[] sampleImages = {R.drawable.magnit, R.drawable.meat, R.drawable.milk, R.drawable.delikatos};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    carouselView = (CarouselView) findViewById(R.id.carouselView);
    carouselView.setPageCount(sampleImages.length);

    carouselView.setImageListener(imageListener);
}

ImageListener imageListener = new ImageListener() {
    @Override
    public void setImageForPosition(int position, ImageView imageView) {
        imageView.setImageResource(sampleImages[position]);
    }
};

}
```

--------------------объявление в xml ---------------------------

```
        <com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView
            android:id="@+id/carouselView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            app:pageColor="#00000000"
            app:radius="6dp"
            app:slideInterval="3000"
            app:strokeColor="#FF777777"
            app:strokeWidth="1dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
```

--------------------объявление в Gradle build.gradle (Module:app) ---------

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
//    compile 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.4'
compile 'com.github.sayyam:carouselview:b8c4e98f89'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

--------------------объявление в Gradle build.gradle (Project:v1) ---------

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вобщем, я использовал обычный ViewFlipper. Напихал внутрь картинок и все работает.

```
 <ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/carouselBanners"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:autoStart="true"
    android:flipInterval="1500"
    android:inAnimation="@anim/flipin"
    android:outAnimation="@anim/flipout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bannersous"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/lenta_banner"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/magnit_banner"/>

</ViewFlipper>
```